# Extracting number from string after a specific character

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I have a dataframe (~1 million rows) with a column ('Product') that contains strings such as 'none', 'q1', 'q123', or 'q12_a123'.

I would like to extract the number that follows the letter 'q' and enter it into another column ('AmountPaid') so that it looks like the following:

```
'Product'    'AmountPaid'
 none            0
 q1              1
 q123            123
 q12_a123        12
```

So far, I have:

```
for i in range(0,1000000):
   if 'q' not in df.loc[i,'Product']:
      df.loc[i,'AmountPaid']=0
   else:
      # set 'AmountPaid' to the number following 'q'
```

Questions:

1. How to extract the number(s) immediately following the letter 'q', but not necessarily everything after it? For example, extract 12 from 'q12_a123'.
2. Most of the 'AmountPaid' entries will be set to 0.  Is there a more efficient way than the for loop and if/else statement above?

Comment: Is the 'Product' field formatted with a q in front followed by the digits you care about, then a non digit or word character, and finally stuff you do not wish to capture?

Comment: @Nathan I had simplified it for this question-the 'Product' field contains entries with the format 'abc_q123_def456' so the 'q' is not actually the first character.  But I only care about the numbers immediately following 'q'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `str.extract` with a lookbehind on the character `'q'`.

```
df['AmountPaid'] = df.Product.str.extract(
      r'(?<=q)(\d+)', expand=False
).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

```
df

    Product  AmountPaid
0      none           0
1        q1           1
2      q123         123
3  q12_a123          12
```

Answer (score 0):

In complement to [cs95's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49458980/16343464),  since [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) only captures what is inside capturing groups, a lookbehind is not needed.

It's possible to use directly `q(\d+)`:

```
df['AmountPaid'] = (df['Product'].str.extract(r'q(\d+)', expand=False)
                                 .fillna(0).astype(int)
                    )
```

Output:

```
    Product AmountPaid
0      none          0
1        q1          1
2      q123        123
3  q12_a123         12
```

This is not just shorter in terms of syntax but also more efficient:

- [regex demo with lookbehind](https://regex101.com/r/56kC1I/1)
- [regex demo without lookbehind](https://regex101.com/r/tiUcum/1)